# Calculation of expected value

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Can somebody help me approach the following problem.

Suppose that we have two independant random variables $A\sim\mathcal{\exp(1)}$,$\Theta\sim U[0,2\pi]$.And also we have a stochastic process $\left\{X_{t}\right\}$, with $X_{t}=A\sin(\omega t+\Theta)$, where $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.We have to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_{t})$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_{t}X_{s})$ ,$s,t>0$

My try :

$\mathbb{E}(X_{t})=\mathbb{E}(A\sin(\omega t+\Theta))=\mathbb{E}(A)\mathbb{E}(\sin(\omega t+\Theta))=\mathbb{E}(\sin(\omega t+\Theta))$

but how we can eastimate the expected value of the last equation ??
The same for the $\mathbb{E}(X_{t}X_{s})=\mathbb{E}(A^{2})\mathbb{E}(\sin(\omega t+\Theta)\sin(\omega s+\Theta))$

Comment: Your last line is wrong, it should be $\mathbb{E}(X_{t}X_{s})=\mathbb{E}(A^2)\mathbb{E}(\sin(\omega t+\Theta)\sin(\omega s+\Theta))=\cos\omega(t-s)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

You just have to use the definition of expectation, for example, for the first integral, we have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\sin(\omega t + \Theta)) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\omega t+\Theta) \,d\Theta \\
\end{align}